# Datapipe.c TCP/IP Socket Redirection

Tags: c, sockets, redirect, tcp, ip

I'm trying to get this code to work, but it's throwing an error concernin the command line argument. Since argc != 5, it won't continue the program. I know (well, I THINK) I need to specify whether it's running on a localhost, remotehost, etc. Here's the code, pulled from https://github.com/bovine/datapipe

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#if defined(__WIN32__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
  #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
  #include <winsock.h>
  #define bzero(p, l) memset(p, 0, l)
  #define bcopy(s, t, l) memmove(t, s, l)
#else
  #include <sys/time.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <strings.h>
  #define recv(x,y,z,a) read(x,y,z)
  #define send(x,y,z,a) write(x,y,z)
  #define closesocket(s) close(s)
  typedef int SOCKET;
#endif

#ifndef INADDR_NONE
#define INADDR_NONE 0xffffffff
#endif


struct client_t
{
  int inuse;
  SOCKET csock, osock;
  time_t activity;
};

#define MAXCLIENTS 20
#define IDLETIMEOUT 300


const char ident[] = "$Id: datapipe.c,v 1.8 1999/01/29 01:21:54 jlawson Exp $";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  SOCKET lsock;
  char buf[4096];
  struct sockaddr_in laddr, oaddr;
  int i;
  struct client_t clients[MAXCLIENTS];


#if defined(__WIN32__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
  /* Winsock needs additional startup activities */
  WSADATA wsadata;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsadata);
#endif


  /* check number of command line arguments */
  if (argc != 5) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s localhost localport remotehost remoteport\n",argv[0]);
    system ("pause");
    return 30;
  }


  /* reset all of the client structures */
  for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++)
    clients[i].inuse = 0;


  /* determine the listener address and port */
  bzero(&laddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  laddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  laddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) atol(argv[2]));
  laddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
  if (!laddr.sin_port) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid listener port\n");
    system ("pause");
    return 20;
  }
  if (laddr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE) {
    struct hostent *n;
    if ((n = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
      perror("gethostbyname");
          system ("pause");
      return 20;
    }    
    bcopy(n->h_addr, (char *) &laddr.sin_addr, n->h_length);
  }


  /* determine the outgoing address and port */
  bzero(&oaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  oaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  oaddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) atol(argv[4]));
  if (!oaddr.sin_port) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid target port\n");
    system ("pause");
    return 25;
  }
  oaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[3]);
  if (oaddr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE) {
    struct hostent *n;
    if ((n = gethostbyname(argv[3])) == NULL) {
      perror("gethostbyname");
      system ("pause");
      return 25;
    }    
    bcopy(n->h_addr, (char *) &oaddr.sin_addr, n->h_length);
  }


  /* create the listener socket */
  if ((lsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    system ("pause");
    return 20;
  }
  if (bind(lsock, (struct sockaddr *)&laddr, sizeof(laddr))) {
    perror("bind");
    system ("pause");
    return 20;
  }
  if (listen(lsock, 5)) {
    perror("listen");
system ("pause");
    return 20;
  }


  /* change the port in the listener struct to zero, since we will
   * use it for binding to outgoing local sockets in the future. */
  laddr.sin_port = htons(0);


  /* fork off into the background. */
#if !defined(__WIN32__) && !defined(WIN32) && !defined(_WIN32)
  if ((i = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    system ("pause");
    return 20;
  }
  if (i > 0)
    return 0;
  setsid();
#endif


  /* main polling loop. */
  while (1)
  {
    fd_set fdsr;
    int maxsock;
    struct timeval tv = {1,0};
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    /* build the list of sockets to check. */
    FD_ZERO(&fdsr);
    FD_SET(lsock, &fdsr);
    maxsock = (int) lsock;
for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++)
  if (clients[i].inuse) {
    FD_SET(clients[i].csock, &fdsr);
    if ((int) clients[i].csock > maxsock)
      maxsock = (int) clients[i].csock;
    FD_SET(clients[i].osock, &fdsr);
    if ((int) clients[i].osock > maxsock)
      maxsock = (int) clients[i].osock;
  }      
if (select(maxsock + 1, &fdsr, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) {
    system ("pause");
  return 30;
}


/* check if there are new connections to accept. */
if (FD_ISSET(lsock, &fdsr))
{
  SOCKET csock = accept(lsock, NULL, 0);

  for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++)
    if (!clients[i].inuse) break;
  if (i < MAXCLIENTS)
  {
    /* connect a socket to the outgoing host/port */
    SOCKET osock;
    if ((osock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
      perror("socket");
      closesocket(csock);
    }
    else if (bind(osock, (struct sockaddr *)&laddr, sizeof(laddr))) {
      perror("bind");
      closesocket(csock);
      closesocket(osock);
    }
    else if (connect(osock, (struct sockaddr *)&oaddr, sizeof(oaddr))) {
      perror("connect");
      closesocket(csock);
      closesocket(osock);
    }
    else {
      clients[i].osock = osock;
      clients[i].csock = csock;
      clients[i].activity = now;
      clients[i].inuse = 1;
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "too many clients\n");
    closesocket(csock);
  }        
}


/* service any client connections that have waiting data. */
for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++)
{
  int nbyt, closeneeded = 0;
  if (!clients[i].inuse) {
    continue;
  } else if (FD_ISSET(clients[i].csock, &fdsr)) {
    if ((nbyt = recv(clients[i].csock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) <= 0 ||
      send(clients[i].osock, buf, nbyt, 0) <= 0) closeneeded = 1;
    else clients[i].activity = now;
  } else if (FD_ISSET(clients[i].osock, &fdsr)) {
    if ((nbyt = recv(clients[i].osock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) <= 0 ||
      send(clients[i].csock, buf, nbyt, 0) <= 0) closeneeded = 1;
    else clients[i].activity = now;
  } else if (now - clients[i].activity > IDLETIMEOUT) {
    closeneeded = 1;
  }
  if (closeneeded) {
    closesocket(clients[i].csock);
    closesocket(clients[i].osock);
    clients[i].inuse = 0;
      }      
    }

  }
  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I just need to find a way to make it work and use it so I can dissect it. Unfortunately, I don't know what to put in it to give it what it needs to make argc = 5, or how to determine what it's running as (localhost,localport,remotehost,remoteport).

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run it. It will output usage information:

```
if (argc != 5) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s localhost localport remotehost remoteport\n",argv[0]);
    system ("pause");
    return 30;
}
```

I would speculate that an example run might be `./datapipe 10.0.0.1 1337 10.0.0.3 1234`, where 10.0.0.1 is the local IP address, and 10.0.0.3 is a remote host.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. 

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go from there. Once it output's the usage information, nothing else happens. Your example run is much appreciated... but I'm not sure how to implement it. If you could give a little more information (if possible) I would be forever grateful.